how do i speed up plotting graph in wpf c#?
hey i am new to coding i am trying to create an app that plots graphs for multiple parameters by reading values from a file. It takes too long to plot lines each lines have at least 10,000 points for at least 8 lines this is how far i have come with the help of chat gpt this is my first app need help. disclaimer i dont have lots of knowledge on coding.
i am using live charts by the way
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using LiveCharts.Defaults;
using System.IO;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public partial class GraphWin : Window
    {

        private List<string> selectedParameters;
        private List<Tuple<double, double>> parameterMinMaxValues;
        private List<double> parameterValues;
        private List<List<double>> allParameterValues;
        private SeriesCollection seriesCollection;
        private LineSeries lineSeries;
        private Button resetButton;
        private Point startPoint;
        private Canvas plotCanvas;
        private Rectangle selectionRectangle;
        private List<Tuple<string, LineSeries,Axis>> parameterLineSeriesList = new List<Tuple<string, LineSeries,Axis>>();
        private Dictionary<string, Color> parameterLineColorMap = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
        public GraphWin(List<string> selectedParameters, List<Tuple<double, double>> parameterMinMaxValues, List<List<double>> allParameterValues)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.selectedParameters = selectedParameters;
            this.parameterMinMaxValues = parameterMinMaxValues;
            this.allParameterValues = allParameterValues;
            SetupGraph();
            AddCheckBoxes();
            InitializeSelectionRectangle();
            chart1.MouseEnter += Chart_MouseEnter;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;

            horizontalLine = new System.Windows.Shapes.Line
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible
            };

            
            verticalLine = new System.Windows.Shapes.Line
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible
            };

            Grid.SetRow(horizontalLine, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(verticalLine, 1);
            chartGrid.Children.Add(horizontalLine);
            chartGrid.Children.Add(verticalLine);

        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void SetupGraph()
        {
            try
            {
                seriesCollection = new SeriesCollection();

                for (int i = 0; i < selectedParameters.Count; i++)
                {
                    string selectedParameter = selectedParameters[i];
                    double minVal = parameterMinMaxValues[i].Item1;
                    double maxVal = parameterMinMaxValues[i].Item2;

                    if (minVal == 0 && maxVal == 0)
                    { 
                        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Skipping parameter" + selectedParameters + "because MinVal and MaxVal are both invalid.");
                        continue; 
                    }

                    LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries
                     {
                         Title = selectedParameters[i],
                         Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
                         StrokeThickness = 1,
                         Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(GetNextColor(i)),
                         PointGeometry = null,
                         Values = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>()
                     };
                    
                    Axis yAxis = new Axis
                    {
                        Title = selectedParameters[i],
                        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(GetNextColor(i)),
                        MinValue = minVal,
                        MaxValue = maxVal
                    };
                    chart1.AxisY.Add(yAxis);
                    Tuple<string, LineSeries, Axis> tuple = new Tuple<string, LineSeries, Axis>(selectedParameters[i], lineSeries, chart1.AxisY[0]);
                    parameterLineSeriesList.Add(tuple);
                    seriesCollection.Add(lineSeries);
                  
                    parameterLineColorMap[selectedParameters[i]] = GetNextColor(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < allParameterValues[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        ObservablePoint dataPoint = new ObservablePoint(j, allParameterValues[i][j]);
                        //lineSeries.Values.Add(dataPoint);
                    }
                    lineSeries.ScalesYAt = i;
                }

                Axis xAxis = new Axis
                {
                    Title = "X Axis",
                    LabelFormatter = value => value.ToString(),
                    MinValue = 0,
                    MaxValue = double.NaN
                };
                chart1.AxisX.Add(xAxis);
                chart1.Series = seriesCollection;
                //chart1.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.X;
                //chart1.Pan = PanningOptions.None;

                resetButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    chart1.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.None;
                    chart1.Pan = PanningOptions.None;
                };

                chart1.MouseEnter += Chart_MouseEnter;
                chart1.MouseMove += Chart_MouseMove;
                chart1.MouseLeave += Chart_MouseLeave;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Error setting up graph: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private Color GetNextColor(int index)
        {
            List<Color> colors = new List<Color>
        {
        Colors.Red,
        Colors.Blue,
        Colors.Green,
        Colors.Orange,
        Colors.Purple,
        Colors.Yellow,
        Colors.Brown,
        Colors.Magenta,
        Colors.Cyan,
        Colors.Gray
    };
            int colorIndex = index % colors.Count;
            return colors[colorIndex];
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void AddCheckBoxes()
        {
            StackPanel stackPanel = this.FindName("stackPanel") as StackPanel;

            if (stackPanel != null)
            {
                
                foreach (var tuple in parameterLineSeriesList)
                {
                    string parameter = tuple.Item1;
                    LineSeries lineSeries = tuple.Item2;

                    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                    checkBox.IsChecked = true;
                    checkBox.Content = parameter;
                    checkBox.Checked += CheckBox_Checked;
                    checkBox.Unchecked += CheckBox_Unchecked;
                    checkBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 25, 15, 0);
                    SolidColorBrush lineColorBrush = lineSeries.Stroke as SolidColorBrush;
                    if (lineColorBrush != null)
                    {
                        checkBox.Foreground = lineColorBrush;
                    }

                    stackPanel.Children.Add(checkBox);
                }
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Zoom = ZoomingOptions.None;
            chart1.AxisX[0].MinValue = double.NaN;
            chart1.AxisX[0].MaxValue = double.NaN;
            chart1.AxisY[0].MinValue = double.NaN;
            chart1.AxisY[0].MaxValue = double.NaN;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void InitializeSelectionRectangle()
        {
            selectionRectangle = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Fill = Brushes.LightBlue,
                Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
            };

            plotCanvas = new Canvas
            {
                Width = chart1.ActualWidth,
                Height = chart1.ActualHeight
            };
            plotCanvas.Children.Add(selectionRectangle);

            var parentContainer = chart1.Parent as Panel;
            if (parentContainer != null)
            {
                parentContainer.Children.Add(plotCanvas);
            }

            chart1.MouseDown += Chart_MouseDown;
            chart1.MouseMove += Chart_MouseMove;
            chart1.MouseUp += Chart_MouseUp;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void Chart_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            {
                startPoint = e.GetPosition(chart1);
                Canvas.SetLeft(selectionRectangle, startPoint.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(selectionRectangle, startPoint.Y);
                selectionRectangle.Width = 0;
                selectionRectangle.Height = 0;
                selectionRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                chart1.CaptureMouse();
            }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       
       
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void Chart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(chartGrid);

            // Position horizontal line
            horizontalLine.X1 = 0;
            horizontalLine.X2 = chartGrid.ActualWidth;
            horizontalLine.Y1 = mousePos.Y;
            horizontalLine.Y2 = mousePos.Y;

            //Position vertical line
            verticalLine.X1 = mousePos.X;
            verticalLine.X2 = mousePos.X;
            verticalLine.Y1 = 0;
            verticalLine.Y2 = chartGrid.ActualHeight;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                if (chart1.IsMouseCaptured)
                {
                    Point endPoint = e.GetPosition(chart1);
                    double width = endPoint.X - startPoint.X;
                    double height = endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y;
                    selectionRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(width);
                    selectionRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(height);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(selectionRectangle, Math.Min(startPoint.X, endPoint.X));
                    Canvas.SetTop(selectionRectangle, Math.Min(startPoint.Y, endPoint.Y));
                }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void Chart_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            {
                chart1.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                selectionRectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

                double left = Canvas.GetLeft(selectionRectangle);
                double top = Canvas.GetTop(selectionRectangle);
                double width = selectionRectangle.Width;
                double height = selectionRectangle.Height;

            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void Chart_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            horizontalLine.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            verticalLine.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            string parameter = checkBox.Content.ToString();

            // Find the corresponding line series and set its visibility to visible
            foreach (var tuple in parameterLineSeriesList)
            {
                if (tuple.Item1 == parameter)
                {
                    tuple.Item2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Show line series
                    tuple.Item3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Show Y axis
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            string parameter = checkBox.Content.ToString();

            // Find the corresponding line series and set its visibility to collapsed
            foreach (var tuple in parameterLineSeriesList)
            {
                if (tuple.Item1 == parameter)
                {
                    tuple.Item2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Hide line series
                    tuple.Item3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Hide Y axis
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private SolidColorBrush GetLineColor(string parameter)
        {
            foreach (var tuple in parameterLineSeriesList)
            {
                string paramName = tuple.Item1;
                LineSeries lineSeries = tuple.Item2;

                if (paramName == parameter)
                {
                    if (lineSeries.Stroke is SolidColorBrush)
                    {
                        return (SolidColorBrush)lineSeries.Stroke;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void Chart_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            horizontalLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            verticalLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            chart1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public List<double> ReadFileForSelectedParameters(string filePath, string selectedParameter)
        {
            List<double> parameterValues = new List<double>();

            try
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
                string[] parameterNames = lines[0].Split(',');
                int parameterIndex = Array.IndexOf(parameterNames, selectedParameter);

                if (parameterIndex == -1)
                {
                    Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Selected parameter not found in the file.");
                    return parameterValues;
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] values = lines[i].Split(',');
                    if (values.Length > parameterIndex)
                    {
                        double value = Convert.ToDouble(values[parameterIndex]);
                        parameterValues.Add(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Error in ReadFileForSelectedParameters: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return parameterValues;
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }
}type here

Trying to plot graph takes too long need help

Start by asking yourself if that amount of datapoints is even reasonable? I really doubt that on the average monitor you have enough resolution for that. So maybe find a suitable data reduction strategy (for display).

You also seem to calculate and paint the graphs synchronously in your ctor. Maybe consider reducing the ctor to initializing the basic settings and calculation and drawing through an event.

And finally, I see room for some micro optimizations, that could accumulate. Like having a static color collection instead of creating a new List of colors in every call to GetNextColor ...

It is always a good idea to start by doing some profiling. That can help find slow parts of the code. But with a huge number of line there is only so much you can do, so you might want to take a look at something like line simplification

Along with the excellent comments by JonasH, I would strongly recommend staying away from AI if you are learning to code. The only way to learn is to write code yourself. That way you have to understand what you are writing (assuming you don't just copy and paste from SO, which is almost as bad), so you'll actually learn. Apart from the high chance that AI will produce rubbish code, you'll never learn that way.

Similar to what Fildor pointed out, what data you display and the datapoints you have dont have to be the same if performance takes a hit. if we take a non-4k monitor you really have (at max) 2000ish pixels to use (horizontally). So sometimes simplifying your data to a separate array and that is bound to the UI is a good idea (i do this for many applications). I usually use the Douglas Peucker line reduction algorithm (will take some reading). and I calculate my spacing based on the width of the UserControl pixels. Also to double down, dont use ChatGPT to do this. It gets a lot wrong.
